# Magento version upgrade from 2.1.7 to magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, version

I want to upgrade my magento version from 2.1.7 to magento 2.3.3
How can i do that. Because both the version supports different php version?
Is there any way for direct upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

there are no any direct method.

you must have to upgrade magento version in proper way and upgrade php version too

> first of all set developer mode
>
> 1. php bin/magento -d memory_limit=6G  maintenance:enable
> 2. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.7
>    --no-update
>
> 3)composer update
>
> 4. remove everything from var, pub/static and generated folder
>    rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/*
>    pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*
> 5. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> 6. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> 7. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> 8. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
> 9. php bin/magento cache:clean
> 10. php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:
>
> 11. php bin/magento --version
> 12. php bin/magento maintenance:disable
> 13. Chnage Php version - based on your upgraded version

after upgrade your custom/3rd party extension may be not compitable with your magento version so please check it properly.

hope this helps you :)